# A way to make temporary connections to battery holders?

Tags: batteries, connector, multimeter, battery-operated

[image: 2xAAA device]

I often need to make connections to these types of battery holders. For example, to power it from an external power supply, and/or to measure current draw in various modes of operation.

I can use my hands to hold probes to the battery-holder terminals, but then I can't push buttons on the device or adjust the multimeter. Alligator clips can't grab onto the flat surface of the positive terminal.

Is there a way to make temporary hands-free connections to these types of battery holders without soldering?

Comment: You could use bits of wood about the same size as the batteries to hold wires against the battery terminals.

Comment: Wrap kapton or electrical tape around a real battery to insulate it. Put copper foil tape on the ends and solder wires to the copper tape. You can also buy dummy batteries, but the ones I have seen are conductive (short from "cathode" to "anode").

Comment: Poke around this website: http://www.batteryeliminatorstore.com/index.php?id_category=4&controller=category

Comment: https://hackaday.com/2013/06/13/dummy-batteries-let-you-use-an-ac-adapter/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magnets. Solder the power connections to the magnets. It will stick to most battery contacts.

I made some with a wood dowel (well, squared) and some copper. Cut to size and shaped to fit in the recess for the battery contact. I added a diode on one and usb connector so I could power a battery led string from usb. (4.3V instead of the new batteries 4.8V).

You could make a small shim from double sided copper clad board. If you cut or etch the copper to shape, you could use a pair of alligator clips on it. It goes between the contact and the battery.

Answer (score 4):

Don't laugh, there are [battery cell size adapters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0064IQ49I). Solder wires to their contacts on the inside.

Comment: Huh. That's pretty neat. But I don't think it would work for AAA or coin cells

Answer (score 1):

You can buy battery compartments for projects and they look just like the one in your picture so, buy one and remove the end faces containing the spring and flat connector.

Take these end faces and glue to a block of compressible foam rubber that can be squished up while inserting into the target battery holder.

Oh, and solder wires from the terminals to some kind of socket of your choice to make the external connections to the power source.

Spring contact on the target mates with flat contact on the squishable insert .